# Redirect if Clicked on a Marker in CartoDB

Tags: javascript, carto, sql, carto-js

How can the user be redirected if he clicks on a marker in CartoDB?

I have a dataset with the markers — the *geometry* and inside of the `description`-field the URL to redirect the user. I know I can redirect the user by calling `on('featureClick')` and then change the `window.location` … but how can I change the `window.location` to set it to the `description`-value of my dataset? I've tried with `sql.execute` but failed (*Access-Control-Allow-Origin………*). Any Ideas?

My Example: (not working)

```
      var d = layers[1].getSubLayer(2),
          d2 = layers[1].getSubLayer(3);

      d.setInteraction(true);
      d.infowindow.set({sanitizeTemplate:false});
      d.infowindow.set('template',$('#infowindow_template').html());

      d2.setInteraction(true);
      d2.on('featureClick', function(e, latlng, pos, data) {
        cartodb.log.log(data.url);
        //window.location = data.url;
      });

                 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/iriberri/a07ce43f1a7f8de3d055) that uses window.open:

You can enable the description column in your infowindows in order to retrieve the data from there and avoid the SQL query.

```
 layer.on('featureClick', function(e, pos, latlng, data) {
        cartodb.log.log(e, pos, latlng, data);
        window.open(data.url);
      });
```

Comment: What could be the problem if I can't retrieve the data? «data» still only contains «cartodb_id» … but nothing else. The columns are enabled in the infowindow-editor — and the viz and dataset have even been set to «public»…

Comment: I'd need to check your viz.json in order to know more :)

Comment: 4e5848f6-084e-11e5-aae7-0e49835281d6

Comment: Why are you getting the second layer of the viz.json in the "d" variable and then using "d2"? According to your viz.json, your first 2 layers only have cartodb_id enabled in the infowindows, so I think that you could be referring to another layer which is not the one you want :)

Comment: d revers to layer 3, d2 to layer 4 (sorry, had deleted to much code in my example — but updated it right now) … I know there is only cartodb_id in the viz.json — thats the problem since in the editor actually ALL columns are enabled! Thats why I'm so irritated…

Comment: Wow, the viz.json should reflect totally the data in the Editor. In the viz.json I inspected, two layers had only cartodb_id but other layers had more interactivity options. Could you check if you're requesting the correct layers? If you notice a discordance between the viz.json and what you're doing, please let us know the specific details at support@cartodb.com

Comment: The layer-selector should be correct. I've sent you a mail. thx.